# Handling pairs of pattern matching in multiple excel files through VB macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have three files - Excel_In1.xls, Excel_In2.xls and Excel_Out.xls.

There are two column say column L,M in Excel_In1.xls which contains keywords (of form product123 and companyABC) I need to search for these pairs of keywords in two columns (say A,B) in Excel_In2.xls. There are multiple rows in Excel_In2.xls with the keywords in that columns A,B.

I need to copy particular columns (say for instance three columns B,X,Z) in all the rows which contain the keyword product123 in the column A and companyABC in column B in Excel_In2.xls to the file Excel_Out.xls.

> What is the best and *simple* way to accomplish this in VB script macros in Excel_Out.xls?

> I also want to open the files Excel_In1.xls and Excel_In2.xls in macro in Excel_Out.xls.

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup as best I could understand it:

[image: Excel_In1.xls]

[image: Excel_In2.xls]

And... This is the code I wrote:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim XLout As Workbook   'Excel_Out.xls
    Dim XLin1 As Workbook   'Excel_In1.xls
    Dim XLin2 As Workbook   'Excel_In2.xls
    Dim ProductList         'Product/Company List from XLin1
    Dim ProductListO()      'Concatenated Version of above
    Dim DataList            'Product/Company List from XLin2
    Dim DataXcol            'Extra Data to pull from Column X in XLin2
    Dim DataZcol            'Extra Data to pull from Column Z in XLin2
    Dim Output()            'Output Array for XLout
    Dim i As Long           'Iterations
    Dim counter As Long     'Item number
    Dim TimeCount
    
    TimeCount = Timer
    
        ' >>> All Workbooks
    Set XLout = ThisWorkbook
    Set XLin1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ccritchlow\Documents\A\Test\Excel_In1.xls")
    Set XLin2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ccritchlow\Documents\A\Test\Excel_In2.xls")
        
        ' >>> Store Source Data in Arrays
    With XLin2.Sheets(1)
        DataList = .Range("A2:B" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        DataXcol = .Range("X2:X" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        DataZcol = .Range("Z2:Z" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    
        ' >>> Store Product List Data in Arrays
    ProductList = XLin1.Sheets(1).Range("L2:M" & XLin1.Sheets(1).Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    ReDim ProductListO(1 To UBound(ProductList, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(ProductList, 1)
        ProductListO(i) = ProductList(i, 1) & "-" & ProductList(i, 2)
    Next i
    
        ' >>> Move entries from XLin2 (that exist on XLin1) into "Output" Array
    ReDim Preserve Output(UBound(DataList, 1), 3)
    counter = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataList, 1)
        DataList(i, 1) = DataList(i, 1) & "-" & DataList(i, 2)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(DataList(i, 1), ProductListO(), 0)) Then
            Debug.Print
            Output(counter, 1) = DataList(i, 2)
            Output(counter, 2) = DataXcol(i, 1)
            Output(counter, 3) = DataZcol(i, 1)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
        ' >>> Output to XLout
    XLout.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Output, 1), 3) = Output()

    Application.StatusBar = "Total Time to review " & UBound(DataList, 1) & " lines = " & Timer - TimeCount

End Sub
```

It does the following

- Is stored on "Excel_Out.xls"
- Opens both "Excel_In#.xls" workbooks
- Stores all required data in arrays
- Identifies data on XLin2 whose "company&productname" exist on XLin1
- Outputs that data to "Excel_Out.xls"

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I tried to keep it short, it got away on me a little, but I still think it's reasonably short. It runs very quickly too. \

Comment: Thank you. What do ReDim and Preserve and Set do?

Comment: Sure: **`ReDim`** = Resize array - **`Preserve`** = Keep existing array data - **`Set`** = I had to look this one up, I just know to use it when setting an object variable, instead of regular data variables. Details can be found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Comment: Also to note, I just made a couple changes to clean it up a bit and to handle larger data sets, and speed tested. It takes ~11 seconds to process 65500 lines of data which isn't really that great, but not too bad.

Comment: You like that answer?

Answer (score 5):

my assumptions:

**Excel_In1.xls == catalog.xlsx** (table has unique key pair `columnA & columnB` in each row)

**Excel_In2.xls == factdata.xlsx**  (table has multiple duplicate key pairs; and contains data in fixed columns to be copied)

**Excel_Out.xls == book Out.xlsm**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TState
    catalog As Object
    selectedData As Object
End Type

Private this As TState

Public Sub ExampleSubMain()
    Init
    PickData
    ExecuteCopying
End Sub

Private Sub Init()
    InitCatalogDictionary
    Set this.selectedData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub InitCatalogDictionary()
    MakeTheBookOpened "D:\vba\somefolder\", "catalog.xlsx"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("catalog.xlsx")
    
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wb.Worksheets("catalogSheet").Range("a2:b10") 'for example "a2:b10"

    Set this.catalog = MakeDict(dataRange)
End Sub

Private Function MakeDict(ByVal dataRange As Range) As Object
    
    Dim result As Object
    Set result = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In dataRange.Rows
        'asumes column A,B are true keys and their pairs are unique, value = empty string
        result.Add Join(Array(row.Cells(1), row.Cells(2))), ""
    Next row
    
    Set MakeDict = result
End Function

Private Sub MakeTheBookOpened(ByVal pathWithSeparator As String, _
                              ByVal wbName As String)
    If TheBookIsOpenedAlready(wbName) Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=pathWithSeparator & wbName, ReadOnly:=True
End Sub

Private Function TheBookIsOpenedAlready(ByVal Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name = Name Then TheBookIsOpenedAlready = True: Exit Function
    Next wb
End Function

Private Sub PickData()
    MakeTheBookOpened "D:\vba\somefolder\", "factdata.xlsx"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("factdata.xlsx")
    
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wb.Worksheets("factSheet").Range("a2:k10") 'for example "a2:k10"
    
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In dataRange.Rows
        Dim key As String
        key = Join(Array(row.Cells(4), row.Cells(6))) 'asumes product123, companyABC columns are there
        If this.catalog.Exists(key) Then this.selectedData.Add row, ""
    Next row
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteCopying()
    If this.selectedData.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rowsNum As Long
    rowsNum = this.selectedData.Count
    
    Dim columnsNum As Long
    columnsNum = 3                               'for example 3
    
    Dim resultArr As Variant
    ReDim resultArr(1 To rowsNum, 1 To columnsNum)
    
    Dim pos As Long
    pos = 1
    
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In this.selectedData
        Dim row As Range
        Set row = item
        resultArr(pos, 1) = row.Cells(2)         'B
        resultArr(pos, 2) = row.Cells(7)         'G
        resultArr(pos, 3) = row.Cells(10)        'J
        pos = pos + 1
    Next item
    
    'book Out.xlsm
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Resize(rowsNum, columnsNum) = resultArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Given two basic input files roughly matching your description:

[image]

and

[image]

And assuming the macro would reside in the out file, we could construct a multi-function macro to accomplish this with a few steps.

The first part of the macro knows filenames and parameters.  You used column `L` in the first input file, but let's make that configurable.  The same with most of the other parameters, like the first line to start on so our input files can have headers.

Second, we need to open the first input file and read the keywords.  There's several ways to do this, but a very simple way to do it is to do a plan CSV line, so that from the first file, you can extract your "keywords" (your term):  `product123,product456`.  This can then be iterated over with a `For Each` loop through the second file.

In the second file, a very simple construct would be to loop over all entries.  Depending on your needs, you may need to iterate through the second file only once if it is prohibitively large.  Both of these function assume the first blank line terminates the input.  If the row in the 2nd input file matches your target, you will perform your copy.

Finally, the copy also takes a CSV line for which columns to keep (keeping it configurable).  Each column, as well as the first keyword, will be copied to the target worksheet, starting at row 1 with a configurable column start.

The final output in the output sheet looks something like this:

[image]

The output starts in the second column because that was what was specified in the configuration.

There may be more elegant approaches, but this is a straight-forward approach to it.

```vb
Const EXCEL_1 As String = "\Excel1.xls"
Const EXCEL_1_KW_COL As String = "A"
Const EXCEL_2 As String = "\Excel2.xls"
Const EXCEL_2_KW_COL As String = "A"
Const EXCEL_2_COPY_COLS As String = "B,E,G"
Const EXCEL_3 As String = "\Excel3.xls"
Const EXCEL_3_TARGET As String = "B"

Public Function LoadInformation3()
  Dim Location As String, Keywords As String
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Location = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  
  Keywords = LoadKeywords(Location & EXCEL_1, EXCEL_1_KW_COL)
  
  Debug.Print "Keys=" & Keywords
  Dim L, CurrentDestRow As Long
  For Each L In Split(Keywords, ",")
    SearchKeywordAndCopy CurrentDestRow, Location & EXCEL_2, Location & EXCEL3, L, EXCEL_2_KW_COL, EXCEL_2_COPY_COLS, EXCEL_3_TARGET
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function

Public Function LoadKeywords(ByVal File As String, ByVal ColumnId As String, Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 2)
  Dim Wb1 As Workbook
  Dim Value As String, N As Long
  Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(File)
  
  N = FirstRow
  LoadKeywords = ""
  Do While True
    Value = Wb1.Sheets(1).Range(ColumnId & N).Text
    If Value = "" Then Exit Do
    LoadKeywords = LoadKeywords & IIf(LoadKeywords = "", "", ",") & Value
    N = N + 1
  Loop
  Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Function

Public Sub SearchKeywordAndCopy(ByRef CurrentDestRow As Long, ByVal FileSource As String, ByVal FileTarget As String, ByVal Keyword As String, ByVal SourceColumn As String, ByVal SourceCopyFrom As String, ByVal DestCopyTo As String)
  Dim WbSource As Workbook, WbDest As Workbook
  Dim Value As String, N As Long
  
  Set WbDest = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  Set WbSource = Workbooks.Open(FileSource)
  
  N = 2
  Do While True
    Value = WbSource.Sheets(1).Range(SourceColumn & N).Text
    If Value = "" Then Exit Do
    If Value <> Keyword Then GoTo NextRow
    
    Dim L, M As Long
    CurrentDestRow = CurrentDestRow + 1
    WbDest.Sheets(1).Range(DestCopyTo & CurrentDestRow).Value = Keyword
    M = 0
    For Each L In Split(SourceCopyFrom, ",")
      Dim CopyValue As String
      CopyValue = WbSource.Sheets(1).Range(L & N).Text
      M = M + 1
      WbDest.Sheets(1).Range(DestCopyTo & CurrentDestRow).Offset(, M).Value = CopyValue
    Next
    
NextRow:
    N = N + 1
  Loop
  
  WbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I made a slight update. Could you take a look?

Comment: @Turbo Again, keeping it simple, the first step would be to read input #1.  I'd read it like `product123:companyABC,product456:companyABC`, and comma-separate.  Very small change for that.  The matching would just involve a multi-condition after splitting the inputs first on `,` and then on `:`.  Of course, if you embed these chars in your "keywords", you would have to escape or protect them somehow with this approach.  Other than that, it would be pretty simple.